# Handling data in AdEvent ICON_TAPPED on Android TV

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, vast, google-ima

Project use ExoPlayer2 with "extension-ima" library for playing video with VAST ad. So player configured with ImaAdsLoader instance, with provided AdEvent.AdEventListener.
This listener catch events in overriden method "onAdEvent" like this

```
 override fun onAdEvent(adEvent: AdEvent) {
                        when (val currentEvent = adEvent.type) {
                            AdEvent.AdEventType.ICON_TAPPED -> {
                                ...
                                // process some action
                                ...
                               }
                        }
}
```

Logcat print message with tag **IMASDK** *"Received ICON_TAPPED event without icon click fallback image list."*

In this some action I need manually start FallbackImageActivity on TV devices (if I understand [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/client-side/android-tv?hl=ru) correctly)

But this activity get parcelable data from bundle by "icon_click_fallback_images" key.

So how I can get this data (with list of IconClickFallbackImage)? Or can I start this activity with some AdsLoader or Exoplayer callback? Google library parse  VAST tag correctly, because icon was rendered on AD, but clicks on icon only call listener method.

[image: FallbackImageActivity will display something like this Activity]